# Javascript Link in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am passing a form via Javascript to a view in Laravel. However, the resulting link is useless. How I can implement the route using Javascript such as the result is `localhost:8000\products.search` not the literal `{{ route('products.search') }}`?

```
var msg ='<form class=\"navbar-form navbar-right\" action=\"{{ 
route(\'products.search\') }}\" method=\"get\">';
```

Comment: If your javascript is within a `.blade.php` file as a `<script>` tag, the above should work fine (barring any syntax errors). If it's a stand-alone `.js` file, you can't use `{{ route(...) }}`, as that's a PHP function.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that code, given you have named a route 'products.search' which points to '/products.search'.

Comment: Do you have a route named `products.search`??

Comment: Thanks Tim, that is precise. I would like to know if there is a way to work with .js file in Laravel.

Comment: I think you could just include a `<script>` before you import your `.js` file with something like `var URL = "{{ route("products.search") }}";` and it should be available in the imported file as `var example = "My URL is " + URL;`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use URL of the route in form action instead of route('products.search')?

If your route URL is something like this:

```
Route::('products.search', 'ProductsSearchController@search')->name('products.search');
```

You can use the URL in form action like this in javascript:

```
var msg ='<form class=\"navbar-form navbar-right\" action=\" /products.search\" method=\"get\">';
```

Note that if you use prefix before route group functions you should implement that prefix before the URL like this:

```
  Route::prefix('inventory')->group(function () {
          Route::('products.search', 'ProductsSearchController@search')->name('products.search');
    });
```

Then you should use the URL like this:

```
var msg ='<form class=\"navbar-form navbar-right\" action=\" /inventory/products.search\" method=\"get\">';
```